# Is it possible to replace the value of a sessionVariable in mule for each iteration

Tags: foreach, mule, esb, payload

I am trying to retrieve some values from the database. Out of which one field is encoded by base64. I need to produce the result by decoding that field. When the Database returns multiple rows as the result I am not able to fetch the decoded value for all the rows. I am using a foreach scope and iterating within the payload and saving the result in a SessionVariable. I am able to save the first row's decoded value. Other all row's values are printed as same as in the Database. Could someone help to resolve this.

Comment: define a variable of type java.util.ArrayList  and then add these values to the list within foreach scope.

Comment: can you show your config in detail so that others will be able to understand ur qsn and answer properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest not to use sessionVars for each iterator...create a POJO equivalent to the Database and then create a ArrayList of that POJO. This will help in the performance as well as in logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are using mule

```
  mule <base64-decoder-transformer/>
```

ideally in you case it should be inside the for-each loop.